# How to get Lollipop "hamburger" as drawer icon in standard Fragment app (without use AppCompat)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

When i use AppCompat lib (v21) i got ActionBar with new style of "hamburger" icon. Is possible to get the same behaviour, but not using AppCompat. I'd like to have standard Holo.Light theme with new "hamburger" (drawer) icon in ActionBar.

[image]

Comment: Why? Also, set the image yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the assets you want from the official github account of Google

Here the link for the xxhdpi density [ic_menu_white xxhdpi](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/navigation/drawable-xxhdpi)

And set it to your Action bar with the method [setIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: What about behaviour like rotating hamburger transformating to arrow ?

Comment: @marioosh that is a behaviour of ActionBarDrawerToggle and I think you can override the method getThemeUpIndicator() to return the drawable you want or customize the style in the application theme by changing the drawerArrowStyle